# How to insert and retrieve UInt32 from sqlite using C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

im trying to store 2 columns and retrieve them back

```
column1 -> string
column2 - > UInt32
```

so how to store and retrieve them back in sqlite using C# ?

and i want to call column1 referring  to it's column2 without any issues.

```
Sample 1
select column1 from table1 where column2 = {this.UInt32_data}
```

Thank's in advance

Comment: what is `column2` for example? is it an ID

Comment: as i mentioned before column1 is a column that handle data type of string

Comment: I mean column2 what data type?

Comment: nvm it's fixed by creating a new dictionary having 2 columns as u wanted to do instead of inserting / retrieving data from sqlite db

Comment: used my answer to retrieve a data from `sqlite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used this function retrieve a data from **sqlite**

```
public DataTable fillDataTable(string sqlCommand)
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     String config = "your connection string";
     using (var con = new SQLiteConnection { ConnectionString = config })
     {
          using (var command = new SQLiteCommand { Connection = con })
          {
               if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                   con.Close();

               con.Open();
               command.CommandText = sqlCommand;

               dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

           }
           return dt;
     }
}
```

Comment: i fixed it using dictionary instead of using sqlite tho but thank's for you help :)